# Paste in Powershell

Tags: powershell, paste

I am creating an Active Directory Restore script with menu based output. One of the functions that the script does is sets the Active Directory object as Authoritative using ntdsutil.exe

The problem I encountered is that if you type the commands manualy you would do the following:

- Type ***ntdsutil*** then press ***Enter***
- Type ***activate instance ntds*** then press ***Enter***
- Type ***authoritative restore*** then press ***Enter***
- Type ***restore subtree "OU=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=com"*** then press ***Enter***
- Type ***quit***
- Type ***quit***

If I want to do all of this using a script then in the script the text should look like this:

**$ntdsutil_job =  "ntdsutil" + " " + '"' + "activate instance ntds" + '"' + " " + '"' + "authoritative restore" + '"' + " " + "'" + "restore " + $Restore_Type + " " + '"' + $Object + '"' + "'" + " " + "quit quit"**

The variable looks like this:

***ntdsutil "activate instance ntds" "authoritative restore" 'restore Subtree "OU=Users,DC=Contoso,DC=com"' quit quit***

Then in the script I put:

**Invoke-Expression $ntdsutil_job**

It all works fine until the OU has a space in it e.g.:

***OU=Test Container,DC=Contoso,DC=com***

The ***ntdsutil*** does not accept if I put ***'OU=Test Container,DC=Contoso,DC=com'***

After long testing I found out that the only way to do it is to PASTE the whole command into PowerShell like this:

***ntdsutil***

***activate instance ntds***

***authoritative restore***

***restore Subtree "OU=Test Container,DC=Contoso,DC=com"***

***quit***

***quit***

If I want the scrip to do the thing for me I don't want to manualy copy and PASTE the info.

So finaly my question:

Is there a way to copy the info into clipboard and then PASTE it back into powershell using a command? Or output the info into a text file and copy the info from the text file and PASTE it back into powershell? I would like to make an emphases on PASTE, not input.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of powershell are you using?  You can check the value of `$PSVersionTable` to see what your current version is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add additional quotes on your DN $object "
It works coreectly in my lab with this :

```
[string]$Object = '"' + $Object + '"'
$ntdsutil_job = "ntdsutil" + " " + '"' + "activate instance ntds" + '"' + " " + '"' + "authoritative restore" + '"' + " " + "'" + "restore object" + " " + "`"$Object`"'" + " " + "quit quit"
Invoke-Expression $ntdsutil_job
```